# JQueryUI radio buttonset not selecting mulitiple sections

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, dom

n my html page I have got two sections, each independent of the other. When I am selecting Check1 and then check2 the choice2 gets unselected and only choice 4 gets selected. I want both choice 2 and choice 4 to be selected.

**HTML**

```
    <div id="radio-gp1">
    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" /><label for="radio1">Choice 1</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio"/><label for="radio2">Choice 2</label>
</div>

<div id="radio-gp2">
    <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radio" /><label for="radio3">Choice 3</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio4" name="radio" /><label for="radio4">Choice 4</label>
</div>

<button id="check1">Check1</button>
<button id="check2">Check2</button>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    $( "#radio-gp1" ).buttonset();
    $( "#radio-gp2" ).buttonset();
    $('#check1').click(function() {
        $('#radio-gp1 input').each(function(){
            $(this).attr('checked','checked');                   
            $( "#radio-gp1" ).buttonset('refresh');
        });
   });
   $('#check2').click(function() {
        $('#radio-gp2 input').each(function(){
            $(this).attr('checked','checked');                   
            $( "#radio-gp2" ).buttonset('refresh');
        });
   }); 
});
```

Not sure where I am going wrong,  here's my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/surysharma/waodj7n5/

Comment: Radio buttons are grouped by their name attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't select multiple of radios that have the same name attribute. You'll want to name your groups separately.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/waodj7n5/1/)

```
<div id="radio-gp1">
    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radiogp1" /><label for="radio1">Choice 1</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radiogp1"/><label for="radio2">Choice 2</label>
</div>

<div id="radio-gp2">
    <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radiogp2" /><label for="radio3">Choice 3</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio4" name="radiogp2" /><label for="radio4">Choice 4</label>
</div>
```